# Why is it possible to have multiple mutable references with static lifetime in same scope

Tags: static, rust, lifetime

Why can I have multiple mutable references to a static type in the same scope?

[My code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1b6f7813c35facba71783ca15ae1b4e6):

```
static mut CURSOR: Option<B> = None;

struct B {
    pub field: u16,
}

impl B {
    pub fn new(value: u16) -> B {
        B { field: value }
    }
}

struct A;

impl A {
    pub fn get_b(&mut self) -> &'static mut B {
        unsafe {
            match CURSOR {
                Some(ref mut cursor) => cursor,
                None => {
                    CURSOR= Some(B::new(10));
                    self.get_b()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // first creation of A, get a mutable reference to b and change its field.
    let mut a = A {};
    let mut b = a.get_b();
    b.field = 15;
    println!("{}", b.field);

    // second creation of A, a the mutable reference to b and change its field.
    let mut a_1 = A {};
    let mut b_1 = a_1.get_b();
    b_1.field = 16;
    println!("{}", b_1.field);

    // Third creation of A, get a mutable reference to b and change its field.
    let mut a_2 = A {};
    let b_2 = a_2.get_b();
    b_2.field = 17;
    println!("{}", b_1.field);

    // now I can change them all
    b.field = 1;
    b_1.field = 2;
    b_2.field = 3;
}
```

I am aware of the [borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/references-and-borrowing.html) rules

- one or more references (`&T`) to a resource,
- exactly one mutable reference (`&mut T`).

In the above code, I have a struct `A` with the `get_b()` method for returning a mutable reference to `B`. With this reference, I can mutate the fields of struct `B`.

The strange thing is that more than one mutable reference can be created in the same scope (`b, b_1, b_2`) and I can use all of them to modify `B`.

Why can I have multiple mutable references with the `'static` lifetime shown in `main()`?

My attempt at explaining this is behavior is that because I am returning a mutable reference with a `'static` lifetime. Every time I call `get_b()` it is returning the same mutable reference. And at the end, it is just one identical reference. Is this thought right? Why am I able to use all of the mutable references got from `get_b()` individually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is only *one* reason for this: **you have lied to the compiler**. You are misusing `unsafe` code and have violated Rust's core tenet about mutable aliasing. You state that you are aware of the borrowing rules, but then you *go out of your way to break them*!

`unsafe` code gives you [a small set of extra abilities](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/unsafety.html), but in exchange **you are now responsible** for avoiding every possible kind of [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). Multiple mutable aliases are undefined behavior.

The fact that there's a `static` involved is completely orthogonal to the problem. You can create multiple mutable references to anything (or nothing) with whatever lifetime you care about:

```
fn foo() -> (&'static i32, &'static i32, &'static i32) {
    let somewhere = 0x42 as *mut i32;
    unsafe { (&*somewhere, &*somewhere, &*somewhere) }
}
```

---

In your original code, you state that calling `get_b` is safe for anyone to do any number of times. This is not true. The entire function should be marked unsafe, along with copious documentation about what is and is not allowed to prevent triggering unsafety. Any `unsafe` block should then have corresponding comments explaining why *that* specific usage doesn't break the rules needed. All of this makes creating and using `unsafe` code more tedious than safe code, but compared to C where *every* line of code is conceptually `unsafe`, it's still a lot better.

You should only use `unsafe` code when you know better than the compiler. For most people in most cases, there is very little reason to create `unsafe` code.

A concrete reminder from [the Firefox developers](https://twitter.com/ManishEarth/status/901269205718155264/photo/1):

[image: zoomed in "this tall to use unsafe" sign]
[image: zoomed out, showing sign is 8+ ft tall]

Comment: Okay, I'll get it I think. Tell me if I am wrong but to recapture: because I use unsafe block to return a reference the rust compiler will not check if there are other mutable when returning one a new one.

Comment: @TimonPost because you use `unsafe` which essentially means "I know what I'm doing, trust me", the compiler trusts that you know what you are doing. Those checks are then disabled for the duration of the block.