# Why does a rustdoc test with unsafe code fail but the same code in an integration test passes?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I am trying to write a rustdoc test of a method called `insert`.
The testing function is called in the last line of the test, and when I comment it out the test passes just fine.

Error message:

```
$ cargo test
   Compiling reproduce v0.1.0 
(file:///home/user/reproduce)                                                           
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.03s
     Running target/debug/deps/reproduce-17ad4bb50aa9c47e

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

   Doc-tests reproduce

running 1 test
test src/lib.rs - MyStruct::method (line 19) ... FAILED

failures:

failures:
    src/lib.rs - MyStruct::method (line 19)

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

error: test failed, to rerun pass '--doc'
```

Code:

````
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new(lsb: u8, step: usize) -> MyStruct {
        let mask: u8 = match lsb {
            1 => 0b0000_0001,
            2 => 0b0000_0011,
            _ => 0b0000_1111
        };

        MyStruct { lsb, mask, step }
    }

    /// # Examples
    /// ```
    /// extern crate reproduce;
    /// extern crate rgb;
    ///
    /// use std::slice;
    /// use rgb::RGB;
    ///
    /// let msg = "This is a secret message".as_bytes();
    /// let img = vec![RGB {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0}; 800*500];
    ///
    /// // Create a reference to the bytes of img
    /// let p: *const Vec<RGB<u8>> = &img;
    /// let p: *const u8 = p as *const u8;
    /// let p: &[u8] = unsafe { 
    ///     slice::from_raw_parts(p, 3*800*500)
    /// };
    ///
    /// let settings = reproduce::MyStruct::new(2, 12);
    /// let new_data = settings.method(p, &msg);
    /// ```
    pub fn method(&self, img: &[u8], msg: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut ret = img.to_vec();
        let mut n = 0;

        for ch in msg.iter() {
            for i in 1..=8/self.lsb {
                let shift = (self.lsb*i) as u32;
                ret[n] = (ret[n] & !self.mask) |
                    (ch & self.mask.rotate_right(shift)).rotate_left(shift);
                n += self.step;
            }
        }

        ret
    }
}
````

Could it be that there are special rules for a rustdoc test to pass (for example the use of `assert!` macro to prove that it returns a proper value)?

*I am asking because my method passes integration test with very similar code, so I am pretty confident it's correct*

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: There are no special rules for test success compared to "standard" Rust tests.

Comment: I am aware that my question is incomplete, but it's very hard to provide a complete one here as it would mean copy-pasting most of my library. I will add the test though.

Comment: Create a minimal reproduction of the problem. That's what all of the links I provided say to do. They do not say to put your entire code in. I'd almost  **guarantee** that you can create something that reproduces the problem with less than 25 lines of code in a completely new Cargo project.

Comment: Okay I will try, thanks.

Comment: That unsafe code seems massively incorrect. Try running your code in Valgrind. I wouldn't be surprised if your test is dying due to a segfault.

Comment: Well it works fine in integration testing...
I changed the names of the variables slighty so it's more clear (still same result).
Now trying to make a minimal reproduction of the problem...

Comment: Just because something compiles means very little as soon as unsafe code enters the picture. Are your integration tests running under Valgrind? Undefined behavior is not deterministic. A concrete reminder from the Firefox developers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224196/155423

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but this is the first time I hear about Valgrind :D
Till I learn how to use it I will post the reproduction of the problem.

Comment: Still I don't understand how the correctness of the unsafe code has anything to do with the fact that the code passes all tests except rustdoc tests...

Comment: Once undefined behavior exists in a program, it is allowed to do anything, meaning that it's entirely possible for it to crash in some cases but not others, so it could just be that the `rustdoc` case is one where it crashes.

Comment: Wait... are you turning a reference to a Vec into a pointer and expect that to point at the elements of the vector instead of the vector itself?

Comment: I am desperately trying to convert or access pixel data as raw bytes... 
The reason I want that is for my library to be able to work with any library that decodes PNGs, instead of just picking one and using its data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that it's running in a rustdoc test. Your code is exhibiting *Undefined Behaviour* because it is *unsound*. Running the same code *outside* of a test also panics for me.

You are making assumptions about how memory is laid out - assumptions that are in no way backed up by any compiler guarantees. A "correct" way to get the pointer would be this:

```
let p = img.as_ptr() as *const u8;
```

However, while this removes the assumption on how the `Vec` is laid out, the rest of the code is *still* assuming the layout of `RGB`. This change stops it panicking for me, but I can't be sure that it is working *correctly* and I can't know if it will break on some other computer, or on mine after the next Rust update.

> I am asking because my method passes integration test with very similar code, so I am pretty confident it's correct

This is exactly the danger of *Undefined Behaviour*, and it's why `unsafe` should be used only in code that is not only well tested but also where the assumptions and guarantees are well understood.

Comment: I see... I fell in the most obvious trap. It turns out the crate `png` takes care of everything. After a lot of investigation I think It's the only png-decoder crate that can give you pixels as raw bytes.