# How can one array contain multiple mutable references to the same object?

Tags: rust

I'm making a tile-based game with structures that span multiple tiles. Every tile under the structure has to have a mutable reference to that structure. For a structure that spans two tiles, the 2D array that represents the map has to simultaneously contain two mutable references to the structure.

I also have a list that mutably owns all my structures (for iteration)

I tried this with `&mut` and failed:

```
let mut all_structures: Vec<Box<Structure>> = Vec::new();
let mut grid: [[Vec<&mut Box<Structure>>; 4]; 4] = Default::default(); // accessed [y][x]

let mut house: Box<Structure> = Box::new(House { });
grid[1][1].push(&mut house);
grid[1][2].push(&mut house);
all_structures.push(house);
```

with error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `house` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:21:21
   |
20 |     grid[1][1].push(&mut house);
   |                     ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
21 |     grid[1][2].push(&mut house);
   |                ---- ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                |
   |                first borrow later used by call
```

Right now this is just single threaded so nothing needs to be thread-safe

I put the code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=trait%20Structure%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20House%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0Aimpl%20Structure%20for%20House%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20all_structures%3A%20Vec%3CBox%3CStructure%3E%3E%20%3D%20Vec%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20grid%3A%20%5B%5BVec%3C%26mut%20Box%3CStructure%3E%3E%3B%204%5D%3B%204%5D%20%3D%20Default%3A%3Adefault()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5By%5D%5Bx%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20house%3A%20Box%3CStructure%3E%20%3D%20Box%3A%3Anew(House%20%7B%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20grid%5B1%5D%5B1%5D.push(%26mut%20house)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20grid%5B1%5D%5B2%5D.push(%26mut%20house)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20all_structures.push(house)%3B%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Hello%2C%20world!%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: "Right now this is just single threaded so nothing needs to be thread-safe" → you can have unsafe programs with multiple mutable references to the same object without needing threads (classical example: you iterate on a vector and try to push some element to it in your loop, common UB in C++), so Rust forbids it.

Comment: Yeah but there's got to be some way to do this otherwise a lot of applications become very difficult. Thats why rust has wrapper types in the first place.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222712/why-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-mutable-references-with-static-lifetime-in-s

Comment: Also related: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-cant-we-have-multiple-mut/23853

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use `Rc<RefCell<Structure>>` instead of `Box<Structure>`.

[`Rc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) supports shared ownership of a value of type `T`, which lets you have multiple pointers to the same object with automatic lifetime management. `Rc<T>` is not thread-safe; you can change to using `Arc` instead if you later find you need thread-safety.

[`RefCell<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html) allows you to enforce the Rust borrowing rules (that is, that there can be either one `&mut` borrow or any number of `&` borrows) at runtime rather than at compile time: this means it's OK to have multiple paths by which you could potentially mutate the same object, so long as you don't actually do so.

I've put a complete example up on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28b28f04005a56372c12f3203d300863). Note that this uses `.borrow()` and `.borrow_mut()`, which will panic if you actually end up violating the borrowing rules (e.g., by mutably borrowing the same `Structure` multiple times at once).